# ASCII value for a character in a given string

Tags: c, ascii

Is there a way to access the ASCII value of the first character in a string? The final task is to sort in alphabetical order and my thought process at the moment is to access the ASCII value and sort it alphabetically
The input is as follows :

```
char *fruits[]={
               "Mango",
               "Apple",
               "Jackfruit",
               "Watermelon",
               "Banana"
               };
```

Comment: The numerical value of a character is the ASCII value. Theoretically there could be other encodings used but in reality ASCII is everywhere. The first character of the first of your strings is `fruits[0][0]`.

Comment: *"...ASCII value of the first character in a string"* this is good point to start, but beware, your sorting algorithm will have to handle stuff if more than one string starts with the same character. For example - "Apple", "Apples", "Applaud".

Comment: Alsom ASCII is just a representation. 'A' is 65 (or 0x41). And it is lesser than 'B', which is 66 (0x42). Any [ASCII table](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+table&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIN960IN960&oq=ascii+t&aqs=chrome.1.69i59j0i433i512j69i57j0i512l2j0i433i512j69i60l2.2967j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) can tell you that.

Comment: You should use tree structure to store

Comment: They are already stored as ascii. `fruits[i][0]` will return the ascii value of the fruits[i] first letter

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII value of a character can be obtained by simply typecasting it to an integer, so you could do something like this

You can obtain the first character of a string by using square brackets similar to an array `string[0]`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char fruits[5][15] = { "Mango", "Apple", "Jackfruit", "Watermelon", "Banana" };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(fruits)/sizeof(fruits[0]); i++)
        printf("The integer representation of %c is %d\n", fruits[i][0], (int)fruits[i][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output ->

```
The integer representation of M is 77
The integer representation of A is 65
The integer representation of J is 74
The integer representation of W is 87
The integer representation of B is 66
```

Comment: For variadic functions, `char` is automatically promoted to `int`.